# How do I open a TCP port

Tags: java, tcp, port

I am beginner of socket programming. I want to open "closed port", i can listening port like

serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

What is the difference between listening / open port and how do i open port. Anyone can help?

Comment: have a look here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't open a port with Java. It's a firewall operation. You can *listen* at a port, which your code sample exemplifies, or you can *connect* to it, by constructing a new Socket(...) with the appropriate hostname:port parameters.

Comment: Not to start a word fight - but "open a port", depending on definition, does not need to be restricted to firewall operations. Although sloppy language, I would say that it is common terminology to "open a port" meaning to bind and accept to a local server side socket; which I think is the operation the OP is about.

Comment: @tbsalling Well you are starting a word fight, aren't you, and the OP is specifically asking about the difference between the terms. And he's marked the answer as correct.